# fprintf always write to the end of the file even when I do rewind(fileptr) before, c++

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io

I want to append a file and update some of its lines at the same time.
After appending as I desired, say I want to change only the first line, here is what I tried:

```
outputptr = fopen(outputName.c_str(), "ar+b");
cout << ftell(outputptr) << " ";
rewind(outputptr);
cout << ftell(outputptr) << "\n";
fprintf(outputptr, "abc");
```

But that code do not replace the first three letters with abc, instead it also appends the file and writes abc to the end. `cout` were 60 and 0 for this case, so pointer in fact is moved to the beginning.

How do I go any line of a given file and modify only that line?

Comment: You opened the file in append mode (note the "a" in the mode string).  So all writes go to the end of the file.

Comment: But when I do "w" it deletes the old file. I want to keep the old file and edit a line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of `'a'` in the mode field says:

(I've cut out the bits that are relevent for this question - it says some other stuff too)

> ... Repositioning operations (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, `rewind`) affects the next
>   input operations, but output operations move the position back to the
>   end of file. ...

You probably want `"r+b"`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: That works quite fine thanks :) . I was actually using that same expression when the first time the document was created (code creates the file first then updates it whenever RAM is full). So should I create a seperate line to create the initial file or is there a more elegant solution to allow this line create the file if it do not exist?

Comment: Yes, if `"r+"` fails, use `"w+"` to create it.